# How to include condition in linear models?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model

I am measuring two related variables
$Y_A$ and $Y_B$,

where $Y_A+Y_B=1$, with different settings for $X$.

I know that each $y$ does not physically depend on $X$, so it’s a constant, as I change $X$. Since $Y$ is a constant, one might wonder why do I even bother to perform this experiment with different settings of $X$. The reason is that the cost of measuring $Y$, almost deterministically depends on $X$. Since $Y$ is constant, I would rather measure it for cheap values of $X$ ($x>1$).

The problem is that I get what I pay for. Measuring $Y$ at different values of $X$, gives me different results, that I attribute to the part of the measuring instrument error, named $Z$. If my $Y$ would have been normally distributed around its average, I would have called it a day. But, by plotting $Y$ against $X$, I am observing that $Y$ measurements follow a linear pattern as $X$ changes, and that there’s heteroskedasticity. I can’t say I’m surprised, given the instrument. Actually, I expect the instrument to give errorless measurements for $x=0$, and for the errors to more or less increase.

Since, there’s not enough money in the world to measure $y$ for $x=0$, I’ll accept $y$ for $x=1$ to be good enough. I’ll even go further and define $y$ for $x=1$ as equal to $y$ for x=0, from which it follows that I accept the instrument to be errorless for $x=1$ as well. Who’s going to object it? Nobody can measure for $x<1$.
The problem is that even though there is enough money in the world to measure $y$ for $x=1$, I don’t have it, but I do have money to measure $Y$ for $x>1$, and my goal is to use these measurements to estimate $y$ for $x=1$, which I defined as equal to $y$ for $x=0$.
So,
$$
E(Y_A|X) := \alpha_A = ct
$$
$$
E(Y_B|X) := \alpha_B = ct
$$

$Z_A$ and $Z_B$ are the instrument errors for measurements of $Y_A$, and $Y_B$ respectively.

$$Z_A = Y_A - \alpha_A$$
$$Z_B = Y_B - \alpha_B$$

$Z_A$ and $Z_B$ must be $0$ for both $x=0$ and $x=1$, by definition, so we can model it as a linear model of $X$ like this

$$Z_A = \beta_AX +\epsilon_i$$
$$Z_B = \beta_BX +\epsilon_i$$

Putting the 2 together, I have
$$Y_A=α_A+β_A X+ϵ_i$$
$$Y_B=α_B+β_B X+ϵ_i$$
And,
$$E(Y_A│X)=α_A$$
$$E(Y_B│X)=α_B$$

And because of some normalization

$$Y_A+Y_B=1$$
$$α_A+α_B=1$$

Which means that I can sum the initial linear models and obtain

$$0=β_A X+β_B X+ϵ_i$$

And then the entire model looks like this, except that the last one doesn’t look proper.

$$Y_A=α_A+β_A X+β_B 0+ϵ_i$$
$$Y_B=α_B+β_A 0+β_B X+ϵ_i$$
$$0=0+β_A X+β_B X+ϵ_i$$

Does it even make sense? Do I even have extra information?
My main question is how to include this extra information.
As an extra, it happens that I can also see in the data that the $Y_A$ and the $Y_B$ models are heteroskedastic and I plan to tackle that using $x_i^{-1}$ weights, or possibly $x_i^{\frac{-1}{2}}$. I strongly suspect they are endogenous as well, but I don’t think I can do anything about it. How bad is that?

Any commentary is highly appreciated, but answers that also suggest R code will be even higher appreciated.